# Highlight active menu and submenu using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, blogger

I have mostly got this work, however I have 2 issues:

1. The Home menu link always remains active
2. When I select a sub-menu item, the sub-menu item shows as active, however I also require the parent to remain active.

See the live site here - http://www.lync.geek.nz/

JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
      aObj[i].className='active';
    }
  }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

HTML Menu:

```
<!-- start navmenu -->
<ul id='nav'>
<li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/tools.html'>Tools</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='/p/admin-tools.html'>Admin Tools</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/call-accounting.html'>Call Accounting/Reporting</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-phone-edition-log-viewer.html'>Phone Edition Log Viewer</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/sonus-sbc-5kswe-log-viewer.html'>Sonus SBC 5k/SWe Log Viewer</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/customer-support-tool.html'>Customer Support Tool</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/powershell-scripts.html'>PowerShell Scripts</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/powershell-one-liners.html'>PowerShell One-Liners</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html'>Lync Updates</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#Lync2013Server'>Lync 2013 Server</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#Lync2010Server'>Lync 2010 Server</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#Lync2013WinClient'>Lync 2013 Client</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#Lync2010WinClient'>Lync 2010 Client</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#LyncMacClient'>Lync for Mac</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#LyncStoreApp'>Lync Store App</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#LyncRoomSystem'>Lync Room System</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/lync-updates.html#LyncPhoneEdition'>Lync Phone Edition</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Training</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='/p/end-user-training.html'>End User</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/troubleshooting.html'>Troubleshooting</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/sip.html'>SIP</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='/p/deployment.html'>Deployment</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/about.html'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='/p/contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- end navmenu -->
```

CSS:

```
/*DROPDOWN MENU MOD*/

/* ----- CSS Nav Menu Styling ----- */
#nav {
margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 1148px;  /* Set your width to fit your blog */
/*font: $(tabs.font); Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
/*color: $(tabs.text.color); Template Designer - Change Font Size */
}

ul#nav li a.active {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #dd7700 none repeat scroll bottom;
    color: #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -goog-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

#nav ul {
/*background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;*/
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
height: 20px; /* Change Height of Menu */
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
padding: 0px;
}

#nav li a {
/*background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;*/
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
display: block;
margin: 0px;
/*font: $(tabs.font); Template Designer - Change Font Type, Size, Etc */
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
/*color: $(tabs.text.color); Template Designer - Change Font Color */
}

#nav ul ul a {
/*color: $(tabs.text.color); Template Designer - Change Color */
}

#nav li > a:hover, #nav ul li:hover {
*/color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); Template Designer - Change Font Color on Hover */
/*background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); Template Designer - Change Font Background on Hover */
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li ul {
/*background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;*/
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Menu Background */
display: none;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
position: absolute;
width: 300px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
z-index:9999;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

#nav li li {
/*background: $(tabs.background.color) $(tabs.background.gradient) repeat-x scroll 0 -800px;*/
_background-image: none; /* Template Designer - Change Background */
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 300px; /* Change Width Of DropDown Menu */
}

#nav li:hover li a {
/*background: $(tabs.selected.background.color); Template Designer - Change Background of Link on Hover */
}

#nav li ul a {
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
}

#nav li ul a:hover, #nav li ul li:hover > a {
/*color: $(tabs.selected.text.color); Template Designer - Change Text Color on Hover */
/*background-color: $(tabs.selected.background.color); Template Designer - Change Background on Hover */
border: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/*DROPDOWN MENU MOD*/
```

Heres an example of what happens:

[image: Example of menu]

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a click event to set which nav element is active?

Comment: I'm certainly no master at this stuff, so it could be a better solution, I just don't know how to implement. I search all over the net and this was the best I could come up with. Also with this being a blogger site, I thought JavaScript might be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rethink your link hierarchy/architecture and restructure your links with folders:

```
<li><a href='/p/tools/'>Tools</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='/p/tools/admin-tools'>
```

and have your pages be "index.html" files in those folders,
(I am assuming a dynamic page is outside your limitations for now)

and for the home page: simply call the index.html there (or what ever it is called) in the link

Comment: Hey Ben, I am not sure Blogger supports that particular structure unfortunately. I had a bit of a look and it doesn't appear to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your home link is always active is that "/" is ALWAYS going to appear in the url.  I think you want to use [document.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname), and test for equality instead.

For the second problem, why not just walk up the parent tree until you are no longer in a link?  Here is an example to fix both problems:

```
if (document.location.pathname == aObj[i].href) {
    var link = aObj;
    while (link.tagName === 'a') {
        link.className = 'active';
        link = link.parentElement;
    }
}
```

Just be sure to remove the active class up the chain in your onmouseout event handler as well.

Comment: Thanks very much. I added as follows, however it seems to have stopped it working altogether: <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function setActive() {
  aObj = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<aObj.length;i++) { 
    if (document.location.pathname == aObj[i].href) {
    var link = aObj;
    while (link.tagName === 'a') {
        link.className = 'active';
        link = link.parentElement;
    }
}
    }
  }
}
//]]>
</script>

Comment: Could you elaborate on the event handlers, this may be my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their input. I managed to get this working, and have fully documented the process on my blog, where you can also see the result.

http://www.lync.geek.nz/2015/02/highlight-current-active-menu-using-jquery-or-javascript.html